# Is RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes thread safe?

Tags: .net

Is RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes thread safe? I can't seem to find any notes on it in the documentation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes. It's [in the "remarks" section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.getbytes.aspx):

> The length of the byte array determines how many cryptographically strong random bytes are produced. This method is thread safe.